# HADOOP REDUCER JAVA - context.write don't write anything

Tags: java, hadoop, reducers

I have a context.write(...) method in my reducer function but it don't write anything. The weird thing is that the System.out.println(...) just above work fine and print the desired result (like you can see on the following screen) :

[Image of the System.out.println trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2dol.png)

Here is the complete code :

```
public class Jointure {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        private boolean tab2 = false; // true quand iteration sur les lignes arrive au tab2

        public void map(Object key, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Arrays.stream(value.toString().split("\\r?\\n")).forEach(line -> { // iterer sur chaque ligne du fichier
                                                                            // input
                if ((!tab2) && (!line.equals(""))) { // si ligne dans tab1
                    String[] parts = line.split(";");
                    int idtoWrite = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    String valueToWrite = parts[1] + ";Table1";
                    try {
                        context.write(new IntWritable(idtoWrite), new Text(valueToWrite)); // creer un couple cle/valeur
                                                                                        // en output
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else if (line.equals("")) { // si séparation des deux tabs
                    tab2 = true;
                } else if (tab2 && (!line.equals(""))) { // si ligne dans tab2
                    String[] parts = line.split(";");
                    int idtoWrite = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    String valueToWrite = parts[1] + ";Table2";
                    try {
                        context.write(new IntWritable(idtoWrite), new Text(valueToWrite)); // creer un couple cle/valeur
                                                                                        // en output
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            ArrayList<String> listPrenom = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> listPays = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Text val : values) {
                String[] parts = val.toString().split(";");
                String nomOuPays = parts[0];
                String table = "";
                try {
                    table = parts[1];
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                if (table.equals("Table1")) {
                    listPrenom.add(nomOuPays);
                } else if (table.equals("Table2")) {
                    listPays.add(nomOuPays);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listPrenom.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listPays.size(); j++) {
                    String toWrite = listPrenom.get(i) + " " + listPays.get(j);
                    System.out.println("=====================WRITE=======================");
                    System.out.println(toWrite);
                    context.write(key, new Text(toWrite));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "jointure");
        job.setJarByClass(Jointure.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Have you got any idea? Thanks for your time.

**EDIT :**

Here are the complete trace of the log when I launch the program :

```
2019-03-14 20:05:03,049 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2019-03-14 20:05:03,116 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2019-03-14 20:05:03,116 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started
2019-03-14 20:05:03,475 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2019-03-14 20:05:03,542 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2019-03-14 20:05:03,564 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2019-03-14 20:05:03,674 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1184033728_0001
2019-03-14 20:05:03,675 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2019-03-14 20:05:03,803 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2019-03-14 20:05:03,803 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1184033728_0001
2019-03-14 20:05:03,804 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
2019-03-14 20:05:03,808 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2019-03-14 20:05:03,808 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2019-03-14 20:05:03,809 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2019-03-14 20:05:03,845 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0
2019-03-14 20:05:03,848 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
2019-03-14 20:05:03,867 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2019-03-14 20:05:03,867 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2019-03-14 20:05:03,918 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2019-03-14 20:05:03,934 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/media/mathis/OS/Cours/Semestre4/Cloud-Internet-objet/Hadoop-MapReduce/inputTab/file-tab:0+56
2019-03-14 20:05:04,046 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2019-03-14 20:05:04,046 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2019-03-14 20:05:04,046 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
2019-03-14 20:05:04,046 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2019-03-14 20:05:04,046 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2019-03-14 20:05:04,049 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2019-03-14 20:05:04,059 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
2019-03-14 20:05:04,059 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2019-03-14 20:05:04,059 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
2019-03-14 20:05:04,059 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 110; bufvoid = 104857600
2019-03-14 20:05:04,059 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214376(104857504); length = 21/6553600
=====================WRITE=======================
Pierre Allemagne
=====================WRITE=======================
Pierre France
=====================WRITE=======================
Jacques France
2019-03-14 20:05:04,184 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
2019-03-14 20:05:04,234 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2019-03-14 20:05:04,237 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
2019-03-14 20:05:04,238 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,250 INFO mapred.Task: Final Counters for attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0: Counters: 18
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=4319
        FILE: Number of bytes written=502994
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=7
        Map output records=6
        Map output bytes=110
        Map output materialized bytes=70
        Input split bytes=158
        Combine input records=6
        Combine output records=3
        Spilled Records=3
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=212860928
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=56
2019-03-14 20:05:04,251 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0
2019-03-14 20:05:04,252 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,256 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for reduce tasks
2019-03-14 20:05:04,256 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0
2019-03-14 20:05:04,269 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2019-03-14 20:05:04,269 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2019-03-14 20:05:04,270 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2019-03-14 20:05:04,274 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@721f3077
2019-03-14 20:05:04,276 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2019-03-14 20:05:04,300 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: MergerManager: memoryLimit=625370688, maxSingleShuffleLimit=156342672, mergeThreshold=412744672, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
2019-03-14 20:05:04,301 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
2019-03-14 20:05:04,321 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0 decomp: 66 len: 70 to MEMORY
2019-03-14 20:05:04,325 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 66 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1184033728_0001_m_000000_0
2019-03-14 20:05:04,326 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 66, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->66
2019-03-14 20:05:04,327 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
2019-03-14 20:05:04,327 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 1 / 1 copied.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,327 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: finalMerge called with 1 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
2019-03-14 20:05:04,433 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
2019-03-14 20:05:04,433 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 60 bytes
2019-03-14 20:05:04,436 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merged 1 segments, 66 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
2019-03-14 20:05:04,438 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 1 files, 70 bytes from disk
2019-03-14 20:05:04,440 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2019-03-14 20:05:04,440 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
2019-03-14 20:05:04,443 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 60 bytes
2019-03-14 20:05:04,445 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 1 / 1 copied.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,493 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
2019-03-14 20:05:04,498 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2019-03-14 20:05:04,504 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 1 / 1 copied.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,505 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2019-03-14 20:05:04,541 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0' to file:/media/mathis/OS/Cours/Semestre4/Cloud-Internet-objet/Hadoop-MapReduce/output
2019-03-14 20:05:04,542 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
2019-03-14 20:05:04,542 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0' done.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,544 INFO mapred.Task: Final Counters for attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0: Counters: 24
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=4491
        FILE: Number of bytes written=503072
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=2
        Reduce shuffle bytes=70
        Reduce input records=3
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=3
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=6
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=212860928
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=8
2019-03-14 20:05:04,544 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1184033728_0001_r_000000_0
2019-03-14 20:05:04,544 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
2019-03-14 20:05:04,807 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1184033728_0001 running in uber mode : false
2019-03-14 20:05:04,811 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2019-03-14 20:05:04,816 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1184033728_0001 completed successfully
2019-03-14 20:05:04,846 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=8810
        FILE: Number of bytes written=1006066
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=7
        Map output records=6
        Map output bytes=110
        Map output materialized bytes=70
        Input split bytes=158
        Combine input records=6
        Combine output records=3
        Reduce input groups=2
        Reduce shuffle bytes=70
        Reduce input records=3
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=6
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=6
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=425721856
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=56
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=8
```

Comment: What parameters do you run the program with? (What's in FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath()?)

Comment: Didn''t look at the code as you state it gives the expected result to stdout and so I asume it is working.  What do the hadoop logs say? Ie. does the result directory already exists when hadoop tries to create it? It shouldn't. But can't say anything for sure without relevant error log.

Comment: Thanks you for your responses.

@ekiryuhin :
This his how I run the program :
1)hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main Jointure.java
2)jar cf jointure.jar Jointure*.class
3)hadoop jar jointure.jar Jointure inputTab output

and there is only one file on the inputTab directory that contains :
1;Pierre
2;Paul
3;Jacques

1;France
1;Allemagne
3;France

Comment: @kai :
No the result directory didn't already exist when I run the program.
I edit my post in order to add the complete trace of the log but there are no errors.

Comment: Think the problem is that you set combiner **and** reducer. So first it executes the combiner which is producing the output to stdout. After that however with the output of the combiner(which is your expected result) as input it runs the reducer(same class) . In that run the split fails( and exception is ignored ), table stays "" and  listPrenom and listPays stay empty.

Comment: Oh seems logic and explain why i had exception on my second part of the split in my reduce function. I delete the combiner and it works perfectly now thanks you a lot. I delete it but just to understand, what is the goal of the combiner?

Comment: Without writing an essay, I'd say it boils down to performance. Depending on what you want to do the additional step helps. I'd say when you need it you will find out ;).